# Capybara runs script twice without a reason

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am dealing with Capybara + Ruby script and have an issue with it. When I run the script, it clicks buttons, fulfills the fields, and saves results. After execution, it starts to run again.

The script starts by reaching the specific page. On this page, there is the `Start new questionnaire` button which has to be clicked, and then all the main processes happen. After clicking the `Apply rating` button, the browser automatically redirects to the page where `Start new questionnaire` appears again (that's OK). But I don't need it to be clicked the second time. I need my script to continue the execution.

**What is the reason my script is trying to run 2 times one part of the code?**

````
    content_rating = browser.find_link(title: 'Content rating')
    content_rating.click
    puts 'Content Rating'
    begin
        start_new_questionary_btn = browser.all(:button, text: 'Start new questionnaire')
        start_new_questionary_btn[0].click
        sleep 2
    rescue
        continue_btn = browser.all(:button, text: 'Continue')
        continue_btn[0].click
    end

    email_address = browser.all(:label, "Email address")
    email_address[0].fill_in(type: 'email', with: 'e-mail', wait: 100)
    email_address[1].fill_in(type: 'email', with: 'e-mail', wait: 100)

    content_questions = browser.all(:xpath, './/div[@class="iarcPageOne"]')
    content_questions[2].click

    ##All the buttons have costant names
    btn_names = ['775', '789', '817', '805', '1036', '1017', '1018', '1019'] 
    for btn_name in btn_names
        current_btn = browser.all(:radio_button, name: btn_name, visible: :all)
        if btn_name == '1036'
            current_btn[0].click
        else
            current_btn[1].click
        end
    end
    browser.click_on('Save questionnaire', wait: 100)
    browser.click_on('Calculate rating', wait: 100)
    browser.click_on('Apply rating', wait: 100)
    sleep 3

    ### Now the code should continue to execute and click ```App content``` (below) but it clicks ```Start new questionnaire``` again ###

    ### App content
    app_content = browser.find_link(title: 'App content')
    app_content.click

    # It skips next two lines and continues with Privacy policy URL
    # If I run the code below separately - everything works perfect
    start_buttons = browser.all(:button, text: 'Start')
    start_buttons[0].click
    privacy_button = browser.find_field('Privacy policy URL', type: 'text')
    privacy_button.fill_in(with: 'privacy')
    sleep 1
    browser.click_on('Save')



       ####### Continuation of the script #######
````

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clicking it again - my guess is there a validation error on the page somewhere and it's opening the same questionnaire again for you to fix the error.  Capybara only does what you tell it to, it's not going to start randomly clicking links.

Also when writing scripts like this there is no need to separate the finds and clicks, prefer something like below

````
browser.click_link(title: 'Content rating')
puts 'Content Rating'
begin
  start_new_questionary_btn = browser.first(:button, text: 'Start new questionnaire').click
  sleep 2
rescue
  browser.first(:button, text: 'Continue').click
end

email_address = browser.all(:label, "Email address")
email_address[0].fill_in(type: 'email', with: 'e-mail', wait: 100)
email_address[1].fill_in(type: 'email', with: 'e-mail', wait: 100)

browser.all(:xpath, 'div.iarcPageOne', minimum: 3]')[2].click

##All the buttons have costant names
['775', '789', '817', '805', '1036', '1017', '1018', '1019'].each do |btn_name|
  current_btn = browser.all(:radio_button, name: btn_name, visible: :all)
  current_btn(btn_name == '1036' ? 0 : 1).click
end
browser.using_wait_time(100) do 
  browser.click_on('Save questionnaire')
  browser.click_on('Calculate rating')
  browser.click_on('Apply rating')
end
sleep 3

### Now the code should continue to execute and click ```App content``` (below) but it clicks ```Start new questionnaire``` again ###

### App content
browser.click_link(title: 'App content')

####### Continuation of the script #######
````

Comment: I just tried what you proposed. It didn't work :( I checked all the intermediate steps and the complete successfully, no errors. After the completion of the ```Content rating``` block, it clicks on ```Start new questionnaire```. After this click it switches to the ```App content``` block. There the code skips two lines where it should click ```Start``` button and tries to continue to execute the code. I added a few lines of the code above so you can see

Comment: And Thomas, thank you for your support with all my Capybara questions here!! :) I know that the quality of the code is not so good but you show me great examples!

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin Why do you keep saying it clicks on "Start new questionairre" again??? What are you basing that on?  With the code you've shown there is 0 chance it is just randomly clicking on something again.  The only thing that can be making it go to the new questionairre page again is the clicking of 'Apply rating'. Which means either that link/button is pointing to the wrong place, or as I stated originally there is a validation error and it's auto redirecting you back there to fix the error.

Comment: I keep saying that it does things twice as I can see the process in the browser window which opens when I run the code. I see it click ```Start new questionnaire```, goes through the code, all steps marked as 'successful' and then by some reason it clicks this button again.
Once it clicked ```Start new questionnaire``` second time it finds ```App content``` link, which had to be clicked after the execution of the ```Content rating``` block. That's why I am not sure that the link is wrong or smth like that

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin  There is absolutely no way Capybara would be clicking a link unless you tell it to click it, so use a debuger (byebug, etc) and set a breakpoint between each action so you can step through.  One of your commands is telling it to click what you think it shouldn't be.